# ModuleAttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, pytorch, predict, pytorch-lightning

I was working on a problem where I worked with pytorch-lightning and swin Transformer, but when I tried to test my model on new data as follows, I got an error :

```
model = Model(config) 
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(f'{config.model.name}/default/version_0/checkpoints/best_loss.ckpt')['state_dict'])
model = model.cuda().eval()
test_dataset = PetfinderDataModule(test, test)
test_predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

Here is the model class, it heritates from LightningModule :

```
class Model(pl.LightningModule):
   def __init__(self, cfg):
       super().__init__()
       self.cfg = cfg
       self.__build_model()
       self._criterion = eval(self.cfg.loss)()
       self.transform = get_default_transforms()
       self.save_hyperparameters(cfg)

   def __build_model(self):
       self.backbone = create_model(
           self.cfg.model.name, pretrained=True, num_classes=0, in_chans=3
       )
       num_features = self.backbone.num_features
       self.fc = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Dropout(0.5), nn.Linear(num_features, self.cfg.model.output_dim)
       )
   def forward(self, x):
       f = self.backbone(x)
       out = self.fc(f)
       return out

   def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
       loss, pred, labels = self.__share_step(batch, 'train')
       return {'loss': loss, 'pred': pred, 'labels': labels}
       
   def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
       loss, pred, labels = self.__share_step(batch, 'val')
       return {'pred': pred, 'labels': labels}

   def __share_step(self, batch, mode):
       images, labels = batch
       labels = labels.float() / 100.0
       images = self.transform(images)
       
       logits = self.forward(images).squeeze(1)
       loss = self._criterion(logits, labels)
       
       pred = logits.sigmoid().detach().cpu() * 100.
       labels = labels.detach().cpu() * 100.
       return loss, pred, labels
       
   def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
       self.__share_epoch_end(outputs, 'train')

   def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
       self.__share_epoch_end(outputs, 'val')
   def __share_epoch_end(self, outputs, mode):
       preds = []
       labels = []
       for out in outputs:
           pred, label = out['pred'], out['labels']
           preds.append(pred)
           labels.append(label)
       preds = torch.cat(preds)
       labels = torch.cat(labels)
       metrics = torch.sqrt(((labels - preds) ** 2).mean())
       self.log(f'{mode}_loss', metrics)

   def configure_optimizers(self):
       optimizer = eval(self.cfg.optimizer.name)(
           self.parameters(), **self.cfg.optimizer.params
       )
       scheduler = eval(self.cfg.scheduler.name)(
           optimizer,
           **self.cfg.scheduler.params
       )
       return [optimizer], [scheduler]
```

then it gives me the following error :

> ModuleAttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict'

I also tried with :

```
test_predictions = model(test_dataset)
```

But a new error occurs :

> AttributeError: 'PetfinderDataModule' object has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score 0):

In either [PyTorch (nn.Module.forward)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.forward) or [PyTorchLightning (LightningModule)](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html) (which basically only abstracts the training and inference details as illustrated in the docs:

> Notice a few things.
>
> 1. It’s the SAME code.
> 2. The PyTorch code IS NOT abstracted - just organized.
> 3. All the other code that’s not in the LightningModule has been automated for you by the trainer.

) there is *no* a `predict` function. When you call the model object, i.e., `model(...)` it calls the model's `__call__` which by its turn returns the `forward` function.

Thus, `model.predict(test_dataset)` should be `model(test_dataset)`. However, I have no idea what is `PetfinderDataModule`, querying it on the search engine doesn't return any helpful results.

Having this said, as mentioned by @Ivan, if you/can use [`Trainer`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html), there is [`Trainer.predict`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html#predict) (which returns the model's `forward` output)

Comment: There is [`Trainer.predict`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html#predict) though.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this @Ivan; I will update my answer. It happens to call `forward` as well.